# 19 months and no decision: At what point should I withdraw my paper?

Tags: publications, mathematics, journals, journal-workflow

I submitted a mathematical paper to a good journal specialized in geometry and topology. By *good* I mean that there is no doubt whatsoever about its scientific standing (e.g. Scimago places it consistently in the first quartile within its subject category).

Now, the problem is that I submitted the paper more than 19 months ago, and yet I have not received any feedback. The journal does not use an online submission system, so to inquire about the status of the submission I need to send an email to the journal's email address.

Approximately six months ago I was informed, upon request, that both referee reports had been received, and that the paper was pending the handling editor's decision. Last week I emailed the journal again (putting the Editor-in-chief on copy) and asked again for news. I was informed that the status has not changed.

I am wondering how long more I should keep waiting before withdrawing the paper. I do not want to withdraw it, knowing that a decision might be close, but at the same time I am getting really frustrated. What would you do in this situation?

Comment: (note: this is a canonical question created because we get tons of questions just like yours: "my paper has been under review for ______, what should I do?" You'll find a bunch of other questions here if you search, too)

Comment: You could ask when it is likely that they will have a decision. But, depending on your topic and the paper, starting over might take a  long time again. Don't push them too hard unless you have another viable option.